# Trick browser into resizing the viewport dimensions by 1px

Tags: javascript, browser, viewport, masonry

I created a website gallery using Masonry, and the site works perfectly fine across all browsers locally. However, when I uploaded it to the server, the images collapse on themselves. The problem is resolved when I resize the browser; this could be as small as a one pixel change.

Is there a way to fool the browser into thinking the viewport has been resized by a pixel immediately after loading the document?

Comment: You most likely need to initialize the masonry plugin *after* the page completely finishes loading.

Comment: Resizing the browser is not the solution to the problem its a hack, please share the link or fiddle and screenshot demonstrating the issue we can look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to 'trick' the browser.

Reinitialize your masonry plugin within a `document.ready()`
Code that lives within a `$(document).ready()` is only run when the page has finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var container = document.querySelector('#container');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    // options...
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 200
  });

});
```

Masonry is reinitialized on the `resize` event which occurs when you resize the browser that's why it's fixed when you do that.

---

If you're not using jQuery, try to use `window.onload()` which is pretty much the same thing.

```
window.onload = function(){
  //code to be run after page is loaded goes here
}
```